# Disabling UIPinchGestureRecognizer with setEnabled:NO

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I have a pinch gesture recognizer attached to my scrollView (one on top of the default one).  I'm trying to enable it and disable it at certain zoom levels but it is not working.  I use the commands:

```
[self.pinchGesture setEnabled:NO];
and
[self.pinchGesture setEnabled:YES];
```

to enable and disable the pinch gesture.  I am trying to debug it and I use this code to print out the description of my gestures:

```
NSArray *gestures = [self.scrollView gestureRecognizers];
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in gestures) {
    NSLog(@"%s, gesture: %@", __FUNCTION__, [gesture description]);
}
```

I see that for my custom gesture it looks like:

```
gesture: <UIPinchGestureRecognizer: 0x88a62d0; state = Possible; enabled = NO; view = <UIScrollView 0x880c360>; target= <(action=handlePinch
```

So even though it is set to `enabled = NO`, the pinch still calls the handlePinch: method.  Is there a reason for this?  Or do I need to use the `[self.scrollView setGestureRecognizers:<#(NSArray *)#>` to remove that pinch gesture?  If I am to go with that approach, do I have to loop through my gestures for the scrollView, save references to those, than set those so I don't set back my custom pinch gesture?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you enable/disable the scroll view itself?

Comment: @Costique Oh sorry, I didn't look at my code and wasn't thinking, I corrected the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enabled scrollview just does that:  enables and disables the scrollview. The Gesture Recognizers are a different animal, that are kind of latched into your scrollview, but behave almost independently.  Why not remove the target for the gesture instead of disabling, then add the target back in when enabling?  Alternatively, set a boolean that your target method checks and ignores the gesture when the boolean is YES.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I thought it would work, but I tried both methods, removeTarget, and having a BOOL flag that my handlePinch: method checks for and I get unwanted behavior.  The scrollView's own delegate methods like scrollViewDidZoom: no longer get called.  When my handlePinch: method gets called, it checks the BOOL and doesn't do anything.  From there scrollViewDidZoom never gets called.  Do I need to pass my gesture somewhere in order for it to get called?

Comment: In that case, I'd remove the gesture recognizer completely, then add it back in when I wanted it again.